# How to find out what type of project I have in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Someone sent me a project and I want to create the same type of project (like... WCF Application or Portable Service Class). I've looked around Visual Studio 2010 and don't see any obvious place where it's stated what type it is.

Does anyone have an answer?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also detect the type of the project by reviewing the files it have. Just have a look at the files.

*.aspx - Web Project
and etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the project file in a text editor - there is a `ProjectGuid` element which identifies the type of project.

See [this list](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx) that maps some of these guids to project types.

Comment: Thanks for the info, although I can't find mine even if I stick it into Google.

Comment: @user738383 - Can't you ask the person directly?

Comment: The person is somewhere in the lost masses of StackOverflow. Although I have found it. I was looking in the ProjectGuid element, but the link directed me to the ProjectTypeGuids element. So the matter is answered.

Answer (score 2):

In the registry

1. [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio{VisualStudioVersion}_Config\Projects\
2. [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio{VisualStudioVersion}_Config\Packages\

The Project TypeId from the project file can be used to find the relevant information under the first registry path. If further information is required you can for the "Package" key searching under the second registry path.

ps. {VisualStudioVersion} must be substituted with the version you are checking against ie. 10.0 (2010) or 11.0 (2012)