# Finding out what type of project it is in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, project, project-types

I want to find the type of a project in visual studio. I found some information when I did research which didn't give any information on how to find the sub type of a WCF project when projecttypeGuid of the .csproj file is compared with the list present on MSDN website and in the below links. When I compare, i'm getting C# and Web application as project types but i have two projecttypeguid's that are separated with semicolon in my .csproj file, which didn't give a way to check what type of WCF project it is.

Some of the the links which I referred are :

1. [How to find out what type of project I have in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343935/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-project-i-have-in-visual-studio-2010)
2. [How do you tell the Visual Studio project type from an existing Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660790/how-do-you-tell-the-visual-studio-project-type-from-an-existing-visual-studio-pr)
3. [determine project type in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031952/determine-project-type-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find this question useful. It identifies registry keys that are supposed to enumerate the project "Types" and "Flavors", which are the first and second guids, respectively.

[What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi)

It may be the case that you'll have to inspect a different registry key, depending on the version of Visual Studio you are using. This example uses Visual Studio version 10 (i.e., VS 2010). When I inspected a "similar" registry path for Visual Studio 12, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`, I found no `Packages` subkey, so the method may have changed.

If you will provide greater detail, such as the version of Visual Studio and ASP.NET, or the specific project GUID, I think we can drum up a more useful response.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you go to the properties window of your project you will see the information following this image below.

[image]

Please look at the output type. It shows Class library. If your project shows windows application then the output is a Windows Application.

Comment: In the future, please don't copy paste answers, even if you wrote them (exact same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38476577/4342319) ). You can flag the question as duplicate if necessary.